# How do I change the stepping of y-axis values in Flot?

Tags: javascript, charts, flot, graphing

I have a graph of memory use over time which looks like:
[image]

I set the `y-axis: { max:n }` value `n` to 1024 (which means 1024MB of RAM).

How do I get Flot to change the y-axis labels so they display:

```
1024
 768
 512
 256
 128
   0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ticks` option for this:

```
yaxis: { max: 1024, ticks: [128, 256, 512, 768, 1024] }
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bj2Hz/), the `markings` option is just to give it a bit of style, if you're after an effect like that at all.